# Why are there audits when the triage queue is full? Don't they just slow us down in clearing the queue?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, triage

About half an hour ago while browsing on SO I noticed the red dot of triage lighting up indicating the queue is full/under heavy load and needs some help clearing it up.

Trying to be a diligent user I opened up the queue to do my part. However after reviewing 3 or 4 posts I got the occasional audit test. This struck me as a bit of an odd thing to do at that time. Now don't get me wrong. I think these audit tests need to be done, and serve a good purpose.

However the timing of doing it while the queue *is full* to the point that the indicator lights up, notifying that people are needed to clear up the queue feels really counterintuitive, as I expect SO wants this queue to be cleared up asap.

Now most test audits are fairly obvious and don't require a lot of time from a single user. However some do take some time (maybe check for duplicate etc.), and if multiple people get these audits I think it causes unnecessary "lag" in the queue.

Am I overestimating the importance of the red indicator lighting up, or should these audits wait until after the load on the queue has loosened?

ps: from reading [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue/295674#295674) answer when i started on how to handle triage queue i got the impression speed was of importance. Since it states (emphasis not mine)

> The primary goal of Triage is to *quickly* sort potentially-problematic...

Comment: Yes, reviews need to happen, but even *more* importantly, reviews need to happen **correctly**.

Comment: The red dot doesn't mean that the queue is full just that it has more items than normal.

Comment: Alright I have overestimated it's importance then. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: If it's urgent, take your time. If it's important, do it now. Urgent thing need to be handle with quality. Imagine 10 people rushing into the queue like robot. We will need to review  their review and the review. There will be no gain. If it's important we need even more quality so take even more time and be sure it's done right. As it's important we need to strat working on it asap so even we our attention to detail we won't have too mutch delay.

Comment: A fail review can really snowball on SO, going from meta post to reopen, each time requesting more people with more rep. Because we let people robot review.

Comment: *"Am I overestimating the importance of the red indicator lighting up"* - actually no, you got it right. It still is a call to arms, to get more people to help clear it. So good that you answered the call. But it is no reason to start running :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Am I overestimating the importance of the red indicator lighting up, or should these audits wait until after the load on the queue has loosened?

I would say a full queue makes these audits **more** important, not less. You almost make that case yourself

> Now most test audits are fairly obvious and don't require alot of time from a single user. However some do take some time (maybe check for duplicate etc.), and if multiple people get these audits I think it causes unnecessary "lag" in the queue.

We don't want reviewing to be *fast*. That's a *feature*, not a bug. We could have people blow through all the queues in a day that way, but we would have a LOT more bad reviews in the process. Forcing people to slow down and consider what they're reviewing helps improve the quality of those reviews. It's great that you want to clear a red queue. Audits are part of the quality assurance.

Comment: My misconception that it had to be done *fast* probably comes from [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295674/8628766) that i read the first time i started the triage which states "The primary goal of Triage is to *quickly* sort potentially-problematic..." (emphasis **not** mine). which seems to be the only resource containing vast information about the triage queue. Thanks for your clear answer.

Comment: @remy It mean "quickly" in the sense of, "don't take the time to actually fix the problems", not "do it as fast as possible, even at the risk of making mistakes". [Triage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triage) is a battlefield concept: doctors with limited resources sort patients based on the extent/severity of their injuries to determine (A) who can wait, (B) who needs urgent attention, and (C) who is too far gone to waste time on. Sounds cruel, but so is reality. The same thing is happening here. Reviewers in Triage are just making decisions about whether a post is fixable or unsalvageable

Comment: I see, that makes sense @CodyGray . All clear now. Thanks for your response